# Is every separately continuous function on $R^2$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

My friend asked me this question a few days ago. I felt it's not right but couldn't find a single counterexample. Any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 &, x = y = 0\\
\frac{x}{y} &, \lvert x\rvert < \lvert y \rvert\\
\frac{y}{x} &, \lvert y\rvert \leqslant \lvert x\rvert. \end{cases}$$

$f$ is separately continuous, but not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Interestingly, $|f|$ has the same property and additionally is symmetric: $|f(x,y)| = |f(y,x)|$.